# Separate Title Page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

With a wordpress blog (preferably the new 3.0), Is there a way to have a different page be the home page of the blog, and put the usual blog posts and such on a separate page, such as www.domain.com/blog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you want to have a static front page that links to your blog.  You can use [Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) to get that.

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages):

> A Page can easily be set to be your
>   site's Front Page. Visit the
>   Administration > Settings > Reading
>   panel and under Front page displays,
>   you can choose to set any (published)
>   Page or Posts Page as the Front Page.
>   The default setting shows your blog
>   with the latest blog posts.

Comment: yes, i've tried this. but once I've done that, how do I get to what used to be the default page, with the blog posts?

Comment: In the Page and Post editors, there is a field for Permalink which is the url for the blog.